# Website contact form submits blank emails

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I'm having an issue with the contact form on my website! 
I've tried searching online for answers but I'm new to this website building and would appreciate a simple answer, if possible. I guess the coding is wrong somewhere but I really wouldn't know where!

**The issue** - 
I receive the email after pressing submit but in my inbox it only displays a subject line and does not show the message, email or the name of the person its from.

Please help!

---

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">

<input name="Name" class="" type="text" value="Name (Required)" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name (Required)') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name (Required)'; }" />

<input name="Email" class="" type="text" value="Email (Required)" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email (Required)') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email (Required)'; }" />

<input name="Subject" class="" type="text" value="Subject" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Subject') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Subject'; }" />

<textarea name="Detail" cols="" rows="" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Describe your project in detail...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Describe your project in detail...'; }">Describe your project in detail...</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" action="submit" value="submit"  class="submitbtn" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" action="reset" value="reset" class="resetbtn" />
</form>
```

---

**and the PHP code:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$detail = $_POST['Detail'];
$to = "info@philippamichael.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";
mail ($to, $subject, $detail, "From" . $name);
echo "Thank You. Your Message has been sent.";

?>
```

Comment: I think your `From` header is formatted incorrectly. Change `"From" . $name` to `"From: " . $email . "\r\n"`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo don't seem to be using `$email` anywhere, and your from header does not have the right format. Maybe something like this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$detail = $_POST['Detail'];

$to = "info@philippamichael.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";
$message = $detail . "\n\nFrom Name: {$name}";
$message .= "\nFrom Address: {$email}";

mail ($to, $subject, $message , "From: info@philippamichael.com");

echo "Thank You. Your Message has been sent.";
```

Notice that I removed your From header entirely, since you don't want to send from an arbitrary address. It's better to use a no-reply address or the like, from your own domain name, and simply include the contact information in the body of the e-mail.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. She asked why she wasn't seeing the email value in the message being sent. I pointed out that it's because you're not including that value in the message of the e-mail you're sending, and suggested a solution.

Comment: The OP identified multiple issues with her email code: _"displays a subject line and does not show the message, email or the name of the person its from."_ This post only identifies a possible solution for one of those problems. In addition, it is stated more as a suggestion without providing any code or reference documentation as to why it should be done this way or how to properly use the `mail()` function.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. This is much more of a complete answer. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **mail** function from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
 bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

The 4th parameter is additional_headers, so your format may be wrong. try:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $detail, "From: " . $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are wrong... Use this syntax.

```
$to = "info@philippamichael.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";
$message = $detail;
$headers = "From: ".$name;
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

This should work.